# How To Play Specified Google Play Music Resources (Albums) via Sonos API

Tags: sonos, google-music

I have ~300 vinyl records which I want to attach RFID tags to so I can place one on an RFID reader and trigger playback of the album on my home Sonos (using Google Play Music).

Is there a way to load a specified resource from a service into a group? I was able to follow through the [Postman](https://developer.sonos.com/code/sonos-with-postman/) tutorial, and was maybe thinking that I could set up each album as a Sonos Favorite and load that, but I'm looking around and see that there is a (very low) limit on how many favorites you can have, so this doesn't seem like a workable solution anymore. I've been digging around the APIs and can't quite find what I'm looking for in the [Control API](https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/).

Ideally I'd have each RFID tag contain something along the lines of artist name, album name, and some Google-Play-Music-specific album ID, which I can use to load the album into a fixed Sonos Group queue. If there's a better approach, however, I'm also all ears.

Answer (score 0):

The Sonos API doesn't offer a way to load and play content from another service (other than commands in the `favorites` namespace) unless that service provides an interface to get the Sonos IDs without authentication. An alternative is to host your own files and build a SMAPI server or use a `mediaUrl` to your audio file in the `track`.

See the [SMAPI sample server](https://developer.sonos.com/tools/sample-servers/smapi-sample-server/) and **Tracks in the cloud queue** in [Play audio (cloud queue)](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/) for details.